# visual studio angular component service mismatches

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio

I'm following a angular course for the second time but now in visual studio instead of vs code because i'm going to add a c# backend.

However yet again i seem to struggle. I don't know what the problem exactly is and don't even know how to call it or google it.

So currently i'm learning about dependency injection and services

So I made a service with some things inside.

On my component i injected the service and tried to call something in my service, however it was not listed in my intellisense so I tried to just type it but yet i got an red underlined error -> very strange.

I tried to clean my solution and then build and somehow it fixed.

Now again I made an eventemitter in the service not listed in my intellisense nor does the component recognize the method.

my service:

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe } from './recipe.model';

export class RecipeService {

  recipeSelected = new EventEmitter<Recipe>();

  private recipes: Recipe[] = [
    new Recipe('A test recipe', 'simple test', 'https://www.maxpixel.net/static/photo/1x/Meat-Recipe-Duck-Tasty-Fry-Food-Duck-Breast-4813261.jpg'),
    new Recipe('A test recipe', 'simple test', 'https://www.maxpixel.net/static/photo/1x/Meat-Recipe-Duck-Tasty-Fry-Food-Duck-Breast-4813261.jpg')
  ];

  getRecipes() {

    return this.recipes.slice();
  }

}
```

Here in my service i do have intellisense for both my getter function getRecipes() aswell as recipes which is private which is strange, but I don't have intellisense for recipeSelected.

my component i'm using the service.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Recipe} from '../../recipe.model'
import { RecipeService } from '../recipe.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipe-item',
  templateUrl: './recipe-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recipe-item.component.css']
})
export class RecipeItemComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() recipe: Recipe;

  constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSelected() {

     
  }

}
```

i'm trying to add the event emitter in the onSelected method.

Does anybody know this stran,ge behaviour and what can I do about it?

I do have to say I have resharper installed aswell as web essentials.

Comment: Heads up: I've replaced your C# tag with a TypeScript one, as your question relates to TypeScript and not C#.

Comment: Typescript is not exactly `C#`, and the default access identifier if not specified is `public`, so it is normal that you can see `getRecipes` accessible because it is. In the `RecipeItemComponent` you only have the `onSelected` handler, I cannot see any `EventEmitter`.

Comment: Yes i know thats exactly the point. whe in my component I only had recipes which is private and NOT getRecipes() which is indeed public and NOT recipeSelected which is public that the strange behaviour, Why do I even see recipes which is set to private. when in my component I do this.recipeService.recipeSelected I do have a red underline

Comment: What do you see when hovering the red underline when you access `this.recipeService.recipeSelected`? What's the error message?

Comment: property 'recipeSelected' does not exist on 'recipeService'.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't configured your service to be injectable. Angular's DI system requires the annotations to be added for the service to be injected in a component

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class RecipeService {
```

Comment: Hmm rather weird nowhere in the course it does say I have to use injectable, but i have checked angular documentation. I assume there is a difference between angular 4 and angular 12 which the course has expanded to it. However this doesn't change the error, I have added the injectable but same error even after rebuilding the project.

Comment: `root` wasn't an option in earlier versions - but `providers` array works in all versions. Btw, that course sounds a tad outdated, v4 is from 2016

Comment: yzes i did the course back in 2017 and now that it is upgraded to v12 i'm doing it again. but still it doesn't work in intellisense, I tried today deleting the visual studio caache but no luck on that either

Comment: OMG i found the issue, so stupid of me apparently I had 2 services one withing the root recipe component and one in the list component which I forgot to delete, so obviously it was importing that one and obviously my coiode was in the other component :(